¿Cómo puedo sobreponer los polígonos encima de la imagen?
Quiero que los polígonos se vayan mostrando encima de la imagen ya que las coordenadas que tienen las areas html son las mismas que toman los poligonos entonces quiero que se muestre esas coordenadas transformadas en los poligonos encima de la imagen
        <img id="medidas_mapa" src="IMAGENPRUEBA.JPG"
            class="imgM" alt="Prueba de mapa de imágenes" usemap="#mapear">
        <!-- Inserta todos los polígonos en el contenedor -->
        <svg class="svg-container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
            <?php echo $polygons_html; ?>
        </svg>
</div>

    <map name="mapear">
        <?php echo $areas_html; ?>
    </map>

<script>
        // Obtener todas las áreas y polígonos del mapa
        const areas = document.querySelectorAll('area');
        const polygons = document.querySelectorAll('polygon');

        // Agregar el evento de mouseover y mouseout a cada área
        areas.forEach((area, index) => {
            area.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                // Mostrar el polígono correspondiente al área actual
                polygons[index].style.display = 'block';
            });
            area.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
                // Ocultar el polígono correspondiente al área actual
                polygons[index].style.display = 'none';
            });
        });

        function enviar(idLoc, idCon) {
            window.open('https://' + window.location.host + '/ticket2/index.php?modulo=localidad&idLoc=' + idLoc + '&idCon=' +
                idCon, '_to');
        }
    </script>```


Agregar un [MCVE]
